# The dimension of a vector space with basis $\{I,C,C^2,\dots, C^{2n}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $C$ be a $n\times n$ real matrix. Let $W$ be the vector space by $\{I,C,C^2,\dots, C^{2n}\}$. The dimension of the vector space $W$ is
>
> > A. $2n$
> >
> > B. at most $n$
> >
> > C. $n^2$
> >
> > D. at most $2n$

I have no idea how those answer might be answer. First of all, number of elements in the basis is $2n+1$. Then one answer might be ***at most $2n+1$***.

Second, it is, $a_{2n}C^{2n}+\dots+a_1C+a_0I=0$. By Caley Hamilton theorem, there is an equation of $C$ which follows the characteristic equation.

Now, $\dots+C^{n-K}(a_{2n-K}C^n+\dots+a_{n-k})+\dots=0$ for some $K$. The middle part can be $0$. Then one answer might be ***at most $n$***

But how can $n^2$ is a possible answer??? Please someone tell me! Thanks.

Comment: You can use examples to rule out possibilities. Consider $C = 0$, then $\dim W = 1$ regardless of $n$.

Comment: actually I stuck at the part $n^2$ could be the answer. (the rest part been shown here) @AlexVong

Comment: I think the question asks which one is correct. So only one of **A, B, C, D** is the answer.

Comment: @AlexVong no no .... the answer is given B and C. But don't understand why C is true!

Comment: No, the answer is wrong, option C is certainly false. As you have said, since we have only $2n + 1$ elements in $\{I, C, \dots, C^{2n}\}$, $\dim \operatorname{span} \{I, C, \dots, C^{2n}\} \le 2n + 1 < n^2$ for all $n \ge 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be the charcteristic polynomial of $C$. It has degree $n$, hence it has the form

$p(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1z+a_0$. By Cayley - Hamilton:

$C^n=-a_{n-1}C^{n-1}-...-a_1C-a_0I$

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: but you can see that I have solved the part "at most $n$" but don't know how to get $n^2$.

Comment: $ \dim W=n^2$ is impossible !

Comment: that is what I thought too. Because number of elements in basis is $2n+1$. So do I assume that the answer is given is wrong?